# Al imprimir una lista de dos objetos en Java solo parece que imprima un objeto

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Holas, apenas estoy entrando al mundo de la programación (Java), y me encuentro con el problema de que al imprimir una lista, solo me está mostrando un objeto y no he podido solucionarlo.

Este es el código del método `main`:

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Alumno alumno1 = new Alumno();
        alumno1.setNombre("Luis");
        alumno1.setEdad(32);
        
        List<Asignatura> listaAsignaturas = new ArrayList<Asignatura>();
        
        Asignatura calculo = new Asignatura("Cálculo", 3.5);
        listaAsignaturas.add(calculo);
        Asignatura lpoo = new Asignatura("LPOO", 4);
        listaAsignaturas.add(lpoo);
        
        System.out.println(listaAsignaturas);
    }
}
```

Esto es lo que me está imprimiendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: El código va como texto!! pero en todo caso yo veo que te imprime 2 objetos

Comment: Asegúrate de que se compila el código automáticamente al modificarlo, porque me da la sensación de que no estás ejecutando el código actual, donde parece que has insertado dos veces el mismo objeto

Comment: Como te ha indicado @Yussef, sí está imprimiendo dos objetos. Los corchetes [] que envuelven los dos objetos que estás imprimiendo denotan que se trata de una lista (la colección ArrayList a la que has incorporado los dos objetos, y que constituye también un objeto de la clase ArrayList). En tu carrera como desarrollador encontrarás que los corchetes son una manera habitual de representar listas o arrays en muchos lenguajes de programación: Java, Python, JavaScript, Ruby, PHP, etc.

Comment: Hola Luis,Bienvenido... tu creas dos asignaturas, que guardas en una lista (List), que no es otra cosa que un contenedor, pero a la hora de imprimir parece que repite el objeto...  
No puedo estar seguro sin ver el código de tu clase **Asignatura**, pero creo que en ella has declarado los atributo **nombre** y **nota** como estáticos, osea: **static String nombre;** y  **static double nota;**, al hacerlo así, todos los objetos que crees, comparten el mismo valor para **nombre** y **nota**, que por supuesto, será el del último objeto creado.

Comment: el código como lo pones no compila, por lo que te recomiendo hacer un [mcve]

Comment: A todos muchas gracias por su ayuda. A @MarcePuente gracias especiales, sin ver la clase Asignatura, como decimos en Colombia le diste al clavo, los atributos estaban estaticos, ya los modifique y funciono. gracias

Comment: Maestro, Un placer ayudarte!!.